# How do i convert a company's internal portal to an android application?

Tags: android, mobile

As my final year project i need to do a project and a company wants me to convert their internal portal to an android mobile app.
They want me to include the following:

```
* a directory/address book 
* events calendar
* Rooms (maybe where applicable), floorplans or location maps
* Corporate News (read from the Corporate Portal)
* Stock information
* Videos 
* Corporate Blogs
* FAQ's
```

I have installed the necessary tools like eclipse, android SDK etc.
Can somebody please guide me in doing it because i'm a beginner.

Thank you,
Aamir

Comment: If your final year project does leverage what you have learnt already, is it likely to qualify as an appropriate project? Perhaps you should start with basic Android app development, for which there is much available on the internet.

Comment: Uh Oh. Any one of those bullet points sounds like a final project in itself if you are truly a 'beginner'

Comment: Your first step is to refine your scope. What you have listed above is a ton of work. I would say a directory addr book and calendar are plenty and can be done in android relatively easy once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 3):

Get Mark Murphy's books, Reto Meier's book, read all of it, and start work. It's going to take you time, but all of what you describe is very possible, you just need to learn, and persist.

http://commonsware.com/

[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Android-Application-Development-Programmer/dp/0470565527](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470565527)

Videos:
http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions.html

Answer (score 0):

I too have to make a feedback portal in android for my company.
I started with learning basics of android,then web services,then web services with database connectivity and making different intent pages and changing languages and other small apps.
You can continue with that.

but,I dont think this is a question for stack overflow.